# Фильтрация списка в Python

Tags: python, list, список, фильтрация

Как отфильтровать список так, чтобы в нем остались только те элементы, которые начинаются с "@". Пример списка:

```
list = ["@mari1977", "просто текст", "Follow", "@ickWil59543298"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = ["@mari1977", "просто текст", "Follow", "@ickWil59543298"]
l = [w for w in lst if w.startswith("@")]
print(l)
```

Не используйте `list` как имя переменой.

Answer (score 4):

в функциональном стиле:

```
items = ["@mari1977", "просто текст", "Follow", "@ickWil59543298"]

res = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith("@"), items))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spisok = ["@mari1977", "просто текст", "Follow", "@ickWil59543298"]  


result = [i for i in spisok if i.startswith('@')] # ответ будет ['@mari1977', '@ickWil59543298']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = ["@mari1977", "просто текст", "Follow", "@ickWil59543298"]
for item in lst:
    if not (s.item [0] == '@'):
         lst.remove (item)
print (lst)
```

Comment: Минус за нерабочий код, за нерабочий алгоритм и просто за халатность. Кто, интересно, плюсанул.